# How to use a lambda expression to return a field from two collections

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Within a c# project I have two collections and I am trying to query them using a lambda to return a value

Pseudo code

> Collection1
>
> alertID
>   SavedItemID
>   SavedName
>
> Collection2
>
> SavedItemID
>   alertID
>   AlertType
>       DateCreated

```
var name = Collection2.where(c => c.savedItemID == Collection1.SavedItemID) return SavedName Property value from collection 1.
```

Basically in the inital query I am hitting collection2 I would like to navigate up from collection2 into collection one to return the Saved Name field. I have never attempted to navigate up through a tree to retrieve another object. Can anyone provide some suggestions on how to build this expression?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you join the collections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) and then [project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) consisting of the fields you care about.

```
var result = from c2 in Collection2
    join c1 in Collection1 on c2.SavedItemID equals c1.SavedItemID
    select new { c2.SavedItemID, c1.SavedName };
```

This is equivalent to

```
var result = Collection2.Join(
    Collection1, 
    c2 => c2.SavedItemId, 
    c1 => c1.SavedItemId, 
        (c2, c1) => new { c2.SavedItemID, c1.SavedName });
```

Comment: The second and third arguments need to be lambdas too when using method syntax, also I think it should be `Collection1.Join(Collection2, …)`.

Comment: Good spot on the lambdas - fixed :). I've put `collection2` first because that's how he has it in the question.

Comment: Then I think you should do the same in the query syntax too.

Comment: Note that you don't "need" to project an anonymous type. You could also `select c1` to return references to the actual items (which already contain the SavedItemID property), or `select c1.SavedName` to return references just to the saved names.  For many readers, that may be obvious, but I've seen several posts recently that indicate that some people are confused by the anonymous type syntax, using it when they don't need it.

Comment: @phoog Agreed, but I was assuming that he wanted values from both collections, as he already knew the `SavedItemID` from C1, so could have done a simple lookup.